# Mock window.document object for out-of-browser jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, dom

I am looking for a way to replicate the window.document object so that I can run jQuery in a non-browser environment.

My goal is to have a set of javascript unit tests that are exercised with MSTest with the help of a .NET javascript interpreter.  I would like to have these javascript unit tests run with the rest of our C# tests.

So far, simple unit tests using the interpreter work fine and behave perfectly, however, throwing jQuery and the use of browser objects into the mix isn't working due to the non-browser environment.  I have searched and cannot find any type of mock/fake document object that I could use.

Comment: Something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not just the document object. Jquery is deeply tied into the browser infrastructure, requiring a full DOM, callbacks, CSS support, etc.

I can't find an equivalent in the clr world, but I have had success running jquery on htmlUnit/rhino.

So, how can you use it? The easiest way would be to create a Java command line app that runs htmlUnit and Rhino as a headerless emulated browser and inject the jsUnit tests you want to run on the command line.

If you want better integration then you could try running htmlUnit and Rhino on IKVM. This way you can trigger your tests from your c# tests directly.

Another is to use Selenium Webdriver/OpenQA. It has a C# interface. You can then run your tests against real browsers or headerless equivalents. This is the approach I use. While developing I run against Chrome so I can see what breaks. I then run it against htmlUnit/Rhino for continuous integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run JavaScript Unit Tests in MSTest, then you should take a look at [Chutzpah](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah). It integrates with Visual Studio and displays the tests and results in the Test Explorer (same panel as the regular C# unit tests). It supports QUnit, Jasmine and Mocha. It uses [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) headless browser so it handles the DOM, etc.

There is a command line test runner that takes either an html file or a js file and it has a VS context menu item for running tests in a selected file.

[Chutzpah Test Adapter for the Test Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe)

[Chutzpah Test Runner Context Menu Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0)

[Chutzpah on GitHub](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah)

As for mocking the document. I suggest you create whatever DOM elements you need, in code, prior to your test. PhantomJS supplies a DOM, so your jQuery code will be able to get at your elements when the test runs in Chutzpah.

I find it very useable.